# ProGuard : Android PortSip obfuscation

Tags: android, proguard

After obfuscated the code, I have the truncated error log:

```
08-05 14:54:34.587  15299-15299/sn.ok E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: sn.ok, PID: 15299
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static or non-static method "Lcom/portsip/PortSipSdk;.unInitializeSDK()V"
            at java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(Native Method)
```

How to obfuscate the following code :

```
static {
        System.loadLibrary("portsipcore");
}
```

**Edit:** After adding the last code, I get this error

```
08-17 19:11:36.517  16967-16967/sn.ok E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: sn.ok, PID: 16967
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no method with name='receiveSIPEvent' signature='(I)V' in class sn/ok/PortSipSdk;
            at sn.ok.PortSipSdk.initializeSDK(Native Method)
            at sn.ok.MyApplicationFubu$1.onPostExecute(SourceFile:331)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2):

The native code is invoking the Java code. ProGuard doesn't (can't) know this, so you have to explicitly preserve the called classes, fields, and methods from being removed or renamed:

```
-keep class com.portsip.PortSipSdk {
    void unInitializeSDK();
}
```

See the ProGuard manual > Examples > [Processing callback methods](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#callback)